# Atualizar BD após inserir registro

Tags: android, sqlite

Uso o seguinte código pra inserir um registro no sqlite:

```
    public void InsereSenha(String Nome, String Senha, String Dica, String Anotacao) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Senha (Nome, Senha, Dica, Anotacao) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try
    {
        database.execSQL(sql, new String[]{Nome, Senha, Dica, Anotacao});
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

}
```

Ele insere o registro, mas ao dar o select pra pegar todos os registros dessa tabela e mostrar num `listview`, não aparece o novo registro, que eu acabei de cadastrar. 
Como dar um "refresh" no bd pra ele pegar o novo registro?

**Edit 1:**

O adapter que deveria exibir os registros que acabei de inserir:

```
        final DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();
    List<Senha> senhas = databaseAccess.getSenha();
    databaseAccess.close();

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), senhas);

    Lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Edit 2:**

Com base na resposta do Márcio Oliveira, refiz o código. 
Assim está funcionando:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView Lista;
List<Senha> senhas;
CustomAdapter adapter;
final DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Lista_Senhas);

    databaseAccess.open();
    senhas = databaseAccess.getSenha();
    databaseAccess.close();

    if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), senhas);
    }else {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    Lista.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

Comment: Como está o código da sua listview? Normalmente o que precisa ser dado refresh é no adapter da listview, que busca os dados do banco.

Comment: Você pode limpar o banco antes de inserir os novos registros

Comment: @MárcioOliveira, editei a pergunta com o código.

Comment: @LeonardoDias, mas preciso manter os registros que já estão no banco.

Comment: @Marceloawq certifique-se que os dados estão, de fato, sendo persistidos. Utilize http://facebook.github.io/stetho/ ou algum app que leia os bancos de dados dos aplicativos no dispositivo. Debug ou imprima alguma coisa no `catch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No banco de dados não precisa fazer nada. Da forma que você implementou, basta recarregar a sua lista de senhas (`List<Senha> senhas`) e notificar o adapter que a lista foi atualizada com um `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Considere em utilizar um CursorLoader/CursorAdapter na listview para acessar o banco diretamente em vez de ficar carregando dados todas as vezes para um array. Dependendo da quantidade de dados, pode deixar a interface lenta ou até crashear.

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo? Não ficou claro como chamar o `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Logo após o código que você dá insert, dentro do try, você reescreve a variável senhas e chama o adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Estou supondo que tudo isso está na mesma Activity. Se não estiver, posta o código completo, tanto da parte que você faz a inserção quanto onde carrega a ListView, que fica mais fácil explicar.

Comment: Editei a resposta, com o código funcionando.